# three lines exist in $L1, L2, L3$ $L1$ : intersecting the z - axis at $P(0,0,2)$ and does not meet the x-y plane. find area of triangle formed

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, plane-geometry

three lines exist in $L1, L2, L3$

$L1$ : intersecting the z - axis at $P(0,0,2)$ and does not meet the x-y plane

$L2$ : passing through origin and through point P

$L3$: passing through origin and making positive angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ with coordinate axes and $\pi / 4$ angle with line $L1$.

find area of triangle formed by the lines and if $\beta = \pi/3$, equation of line $L1$?

**My Approach**

I got line L2 since it would just be z=0 but for line L1 and L2 I am confused as to what relations or equations I should use to get them

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I got line L2 since it would just be z=0 but for line L1 and L2 I am confused as to what relations or equations I should use to get them

Comment: No ! Line $L_2$ (which is $z$ axis) has equation$\color{red}{s} \ x=y=0$. But you don't need equations. Just observe that for any $L_1$, the $\pi/4$ angle condition gives you a *right isoceles* triangle where the sides of the right angle have length 2.

Comment: What is the source of this question?  There seems to be insufficient information.

Answer (score 0):

Intersection of Lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ is $P$, the intersection of lines $L_2$ and $L_3$ is the origin $O$. Let's call $Q$ the intersection of lines $L_1$ and $L_3$. Since we know that $L_1$ does not intersect the $x-y$ plane, it means that the $z$ coordinates of all the points on the line is the same. Since $P=(0,0,2)$, it means that $Q$ has coordinates $(a,b,2)$. Since we know that $\angle OQP=\pi/4$, we write the area of the triangle using vector product. $$A_{OPQ}=\frac12|\vec{OQ}\times\vec{PQ}|=\frac12|OQ||QP|\sin\frac\pi4\\=\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2^2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
At the same time, we can write the scalar product
$$|\vec{OQ}\cdot\vec {QP}|=(a,b,2)\cdot(a,b,0)=a^2+b^2\\=|OQ||QP|\cos\frac\pi 4=\frac{\sqrt 2}2\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2^2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
From here, you can square the last terms in each of the above lines:
$$(a^2+b^2)^2=\frac12(a^2+b^2+4)(a^2+b^2)$$
which yields $a^2+b^2=4$. This confirms one of the comments for the question, that you have an isosceles triangle ($\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=2$ is the length of $PQ$, same as $PO$).
Then $$A_{OPQ}=\frac{\sqrt 2}4\sqrt{4+4}\sqrt 4=2$$
To find the equation of the line, you need to find one more relationship between $a$ and $b$. Use the angle $\beta$. Write the $\cos\beta$ in terms of the scalar product of $OQ$ with the $y$ axis.